# Cannot connect vSphere ESXi 7 with Web client

Tags: vmware, vsphere, esxi

I am installing VMware vSphre ESXi 7.0.2.  But I cannot use web client (http://<ip_address>/ui)

When installed first time, I can connect with https://<IP_address> (It will be redirect to https://<IP_address>/ui ) and can create VM.  But I found I cannot use some SDD/HDD.  So I have re-installed ESXi after created the RAID partitions.

Re-Install was look OK, and I can see DCUI and set IP, DNS etc...  After all set, I've tried to use https://<IP_address>. But it was timed out.  (I have checked several things, then I found the ping does not work.)

I restarted the server then ping is OK.  But when I try to connect with https://<IP_address> then the ping became "Destination net unreachable".  (I have confirmed it with "-t" option.)

I thought it is firewall settings.  So, I changed "--default-action" and "--enabled" but it still not working.  Just in case, I have stop to use RAID disks and re-install it again (it is same as first installation), but it was same results.

Answer (score 1):

There's likely still a networking-related misconfiguration. Use DCUI to verify IP/subnet mask/gateway/VLAN tag (if necessary) and that the appropriate NIC has been configured.

If those are set correctly, the DCUI also has some built-in testing options which allows you to do some outbound ping testing. By default it will check 3 hosts, including the gateway and usually two DNS names, but those can be changed to other options.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I have checked with ping tool for Default GW, DNS(primary), DNS(secondary) and hostname.   It is OK after restarted, but will be failed after try to connect the Host Client.  There is an another server, which is installed older ESXi (6.0 and 6.5).  They have similller settings, but do not have any problem.  (I am doubting about hardware problem, now.)